# Convert Raw image to JPG

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, libraw

I have the following issues when I try to run:
the input would be something like
file=/Downloads/canon_eos_70d_20.CR2

```
with Raw(file) as raw_image:
        buffered_image = np.array(raw_image.to_buffer())
        im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (raw_image.metadata.width, raw_image.metadata.height), buffered_image, 'raw',
                              'RGB', 0, 1)
        im.save(os.path.split(file)[1] + '.jpg')
        print('Successfully saved file as JPG.')


'Unsupported Libraw version: %s.%s.%s.' % self.version_number
```

> ImportError: Unsupported Libraw version: 0.19.2.

Any ideas?
if not did anyone tried any other way to convert RAW images to jpg?

Comment: Are you using rawkit?

Comment: yes, I am doing. This is the only way that I found. any other suggestion @Roope

Comment: if that's all you're doing why not just use `dcraw` directly?

Comment: Could you give me an example @SamMason

Comment: `dcraw` is the original program behind `LibRaw`.  you can just run `dcraw -c filename.cr2 | cjpeg > filename.jpg` at the command line as described on various tutorials on the web

Comment: I need to use it inside python script @SamMason

Comment: you should probably just install a supported version of libraw then.  Pillow does support PPM formatted files, which `dcraw` outputs by default.  it would be easy to run `dcraw` using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and do postprocessing from there.  depends why you're using python

Comment: Have you tried rawpy instead? https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using rawpy(had a postprocessing I could not seem to understand
) or rawkit (had complications with Libraw). Use PIL

```
from PIL import Image

file = r"/Downloads/canon_eos_70d_20.CR2"
im = Image.open(file)
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
rgb_im.save(file[:-4]+'.JPG')
```

Answer (score 0):

The front page of the [rawkit documentation](https://rawkit.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/) states this under requirements:

> - LibRaw 0.16.x (API version 10)
> - LibRaw 0.17.x (API version 11)

Should be clear then that 0.19.x is not supported.